# Route directory with React Router

Tags: reactjs, routes

I used to have my homepage in `/home`. I want to migrate it to the base url `/`.

When I did

```
<Route
    path="home"         
    component={HomePage}
/>
```

I could access the page at `localhost/home`

If I want to use the base directory, I get a blank page, I have tried

```
<Route
    path=""         
    component={HomePage}
/>
```

and (just in case)

```
<Route
    path="/"            
    component={HomePage}
/>
```

The `App.js` is receiving empty `props.children` too, although I am only sending an empty string as the path name and the rest remains the same.

What the app renders is this

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the route is not an empty string, the props children is full of properties like key, props, type, etc

Comment: Have you tried `<Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />`?

Comment: @Tholle thanks, I just tried it but no, it doesn't work

Comment: Alright, bummer. Do you think you could show more of your code, maybe your entire `App` component? It will be hard to see what's wrong from the current code.

Comment: @Tholle I added it to the question